# Maya Python. Parenting groups with for loop

Tags: python, maya

So I've been working on an autorigger for the fingers based on the antcgi methos used in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vJxXLw16Ak&t=1150s

The script itself is easy to use, Just create any 5 joint chain, select the root of the joint, and hit "build finger control" ignore the rest of the buttons because they dont really do anything without the full autorigger

the problem I've run into is around lines 162 to 167. The for loop above it creates the controls just fine: but I want it to parent the controls properly in a hierarchy. Lines 170 to 171 work fine: but they arent very malleable and due to the names being semi hardcoded this script doesn't work on the thumb chain as a result.

Any time I try to use the rel = pm.ls loop, I just get an error saying "'list' object has no attribute 'replace' #"

Here is the script for anyone willing to take a crack at it:

```
'''
import DS_humanFingerPresetBuilder_V1
reload (DS_humanFingerPresetBuilder_V1)
DS_humanFingerPresetBuilder_V1.gui()
'''
import maya.cmds as pm

if pm.window("autoArmWin", exists =True):
    pm.deleteUI("autoArmWin", window = True)

myWindow = pm.window("autoArmWin",t='DS_handOmatic_V3',rtf=1,w=100, h=100, toolbox=True)
column = pm.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui(*args):
    pm.columnLayout()
    pm.button(w=300,label='Print Instructions(Check Script Editor)',c=printInstructions)
    pm.separator(w=300, h=3)
    pm.rowColumnLayout( numberOfRows=1 )
    pm.optionMenu('primePref',label='Select Primer',w=300)
    pm.menuItem( label='Build Offset Group')
    pm.menuItem( label='Prime Finger')
    pm.setParent('..')
    pm.button(w=300,label='Prime Game Finger',c=primeGameFinger)
    pm.separator( w=300, h=9)

    pm.rowColumnLayout( numberOfRows=1 )
    pm.optionMenu('axisPref',label='Select Aim Axis',w=300)
    pm.menuItem( label='X')
    pm.menuItem( label='Y')
    pm.menuItem( label='Z')
    pm.setParent('..')

    pm.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2)
    pm.optionMenu('sidePref',label='Select Side      ',w=300)
    pm.menuItem( label='lf' )
    pm.menuItem( label='rt' )
    pm.menuItem( label='ct' )
    pm.setParent('..')

    pm.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2)
    pm.optionMenu('fingPref',label='Select Finger  ',w=300)
    pm.menuItem( label='Index' )
    pm.menuItem( label='Middle' )
    pm.menuItem( label='Ring' )
    pm.menuItem( label='Pinky' )
    pm.menuItem( label='Thumb' )
    pm.setParent('..')

    pm.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2)
    pm.text(l='Set Increment  ')
    pm.textField('incText',it = '1',editable=True,w=220)
    pm.setParent('..')

    pm.colorIndexSliderGrp('controlColor',
        label='Control Color',
        min=0,
        max=31,
        value=1,
        columnWidth=[( 1, 80 ),( 2, 40 ), ( 3, 150 )])

    pm.separator()
    pm.button(w=300,label= "Build Finger Control",c=buildTemplate)
    pm.separator()
    pm.showWindow(myWindow)

    pm.separator( w=300, h=9)
    pm.button(w=300,label='Cleanup Heirarchy',bgc=(0.850,0.534,0.151),c=cleanup)

    # add increment to arm tool to allow multiple limb creation

def primeGameFinger(*args):
    primePref = pm.optionMenu('primePref',query=True,value=True)
    sidePref = pm.optionMenu('sidePref',query=True,value=True)
    incPref = pm.textField('incText', query=True, text=True)
    handSide = sidePref + incPref

    root = pm.ls(sl=True)[0]
    child = pm.listRelatives(root,ad=1,type='joint')
    child.append(root)
    child.reverse()
    limbJnt = child

    print(child)

    if primePref == 'Build Offset Group':
        pm.group(n=handSide + '_hand_CTRL_offset_GRP',empty=True,world=True)
        pm.parentConstraint(handSide+'_wrist_BIND',handSide + '_hand_CTRL_offset_GRP',mo=False)

    elif primePref == 'Prime Finger':
        pm.parent(root,handSide+'_wrist_BIND')

        root = pm.ls(sl=True)[0]
        child = pm.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
        child.append(root)
        limbJnt = child

        #rename the arm joints
        for j, name in enumerate(child):
            pm.rename(name,'temp{0}_BIND_JNT'.format(len(child)-j))
            print(child)

def buildTemplate(*args):
    sidePref = pm.optionMenu('sidePref',query=True,value=True)
    fingerPref = pm.optionMenu('fingPref',query=True,value=True)
    incPref = pm.textField('incText', query=True, text=True)

    colorPref = pm.colorIndexSliderGrp('controlColor',query=True,value=True) #this variable links to the color slider group in the GUI
    colorPref = colorPref -1 # this reverses the first variable to ensure you are getting the proper color from the color selector

    fingerTemplate = sidePref +'_'+ fingerPref +'_'+ incPref

    lookFor = fingerTemplate +'AJ'

    #rename finger joints
    #list all joints in chain, this list will be refrenced by all the commands beneath it
    root = pm.ls(sl=True)
    child = pm.listRelatives(root,ad=1,children=True,type='joint')#I removed f=True flag to get it to ignore the clavicle glitch
    child.append(root)
    limbJnt = child

    #rename the arm joints
    for j, name in enumerate(child):
        pm.rename(name,fingerTemplate + 'AJ{0}_BIND_JNT'.format(len(child)-j))

    #rename beggining and end joints to start and end respectivly
    root = pm.ls(sl=True)
    child = pm.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
    pm.rename(child[0],fingerTemplate +'AJ_BIND_END_JNT')

    root = pm.ls(sl=True)
    child = pm.listRelatives(root,ad=1,children=True,type='joint')#I removed f=True flag to get it to ignore the clavicle glitch
    child.append(root)
    child.remove(child[0])
    child.remove(child[-1])
    limbJnt = child

    print(child)

    #build FK finger controls
    for j in limbJnt:
            grpN = j.replace('_JNT','Orient_GRP') #create the name for the first offset group 
            grpM = j.replace('_JNT','Modify_GRP') #create the name for the second offset group
            ctl = j.replace('_JNT','_CTRL') #create the name for the fk control (will eventually have shape and color options)

            #this block of text links back to the option menu and allows different shape creation 
            pm.curve(n=ctl, d=1,p=[(0,0,0),(0,2,0),(-1,3,0),(1,3,0),(0,2,0)])

            pm.group(n=grpN,em=1) #create the first offset group
            pm.group(n=grpM,em=1) #create the second offset group
            pm.parent(ctl,grpM) #parent the control under the proper group 
            pm.parent(grpM,grpN) #parent the groups accordingly

            tmpCons = pm.parentConstraint(j, grpN,mo=False)#create temporary constraint to pop FK control offset into place
            pm.delete(tmpCons) #delete temporary constraint group when no longer needed

            linkCons = pm.parentConstraint(ctl,j,mo=False)#parent constraint the FK joint to the proper control

            pm.setAttr(ctl + '.overrideEnabled', 1)
            pm.setAttr(ctl + '.overrideColor', colorPref)#create a textfield for manually enterring the number of the color:

            #this line is supposed to parent the finger fk controls properly: but it's being a little shit
            '''
            rel = pm.listRelatives(j, p=1)
            if rel:
                if lookFor in rel[0]:
                    rel = rel[0].replace('_JNT', '_CTRL')
                    pm.parent(grpN, rel)
            '''
    #this chunk will be redundant when you figure out to make the list relatives above parent controls in the proper order
    pm.parent(fingerTemplate+'AJ4_BINDOrient_GRP',fingerTemplate+'AJ3_BIND_CTRL')
    pm.parent(fingerTemplate+'AJ3_BINDOrient_GRP',fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL')
    #pm.parent(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BINDOrient_GRP',sidePref+incPref+'_hand_CTRL_offset_GRP')

    #add attributes to controls
    pm.addAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL',ln='Y_Translate', attributeType='float', keyable=True)
    pm.addAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL',ln='Z_Translate', attributeType='float', keyable=True)
    pm.addAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL',ln='X_Translate', attributeType='float', keyable=True)

    #create and link nodes
    pm.setAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.Y_Translate',30)
    pm.setAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.Z_Translate',-30)
    pm.setAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.X_Translate',0.25)

    pm.createNode('multiplyDivide',n=fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv')

    #Build and connect Nodes for metacarpal rotation

    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.translateY',fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.input1X')

    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.outputX',fingerTemplate+'AJ1_BIND_JNT'+'.rotateZ')#joint Connect

    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.translateZ',fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.input1Y')

    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.outputY',fingerTemplate+'AJ1_BIND_JNT'+'.rotateY')#joint Connect
    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.rotateX',fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.input1Z')

    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.outputZ',fingerTemplate+'AJ1_BIND_JNT'+'.rotateX')#joint Connect

    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.Y_Translate',fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.input2X')
    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.Z_Translate',fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.input2Y')

    #figure out what X is supposed to do
    pm.connectAttr(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BIND_CTRL'+'.X_Translate',fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv.input2Z')


def cleanup(*args):
    pass

def printInstructions(*args):
    print"Step 1: Select your finger joint: it should have 5 joints"
    print"        -The first finger joint should be a matacarpal torwards the end of the wrist"
    print"        -until updated: it's recomended your finger joints have an X Aim axis"
    print"Step 2: If you are using the full autorigger, follow steps 3 through 4: otherwise skip them"
    print"Step 3: Hit prime game finger to create an offset group for your finger controls"
    print"Step 4: Change the pulldown next to Select Primer to PrimeFinger and hit Prime Game Finger again"

    print"Step 5: Select your aim axis"
    print"Step 6: Select your side"
    print"Step 7: Select your finger type"
    print"Step 8: with the root joint of your finger selected: hit build finger controls"

    print"Step 9: when you are finished, hit Cleanup Heirarchy to place it in the right place in the rig heirarchy(Full autorigger required)"
```

Comment: You absolutely need to start using long names with `cmds`. It builds the rig ok if there's a single joint chain in the scene, but completely falls apart if there's duplicate names in different hierarchies. If you don't use long names then Maya will be confused and spit out `More than one object matches name` errors. From what I can see this is the major issue going on. With `cmds.listRelatives` use the `full` parameter, otherwise brace yourself for constant pitfalls like this.

Comment: Any reason .cmds is considered better than .pm or .mc? I always thought it just came down to personal preference. I remember reading .pm is supposed to interface better with python commands. Also when you say full parameter: do you mean the fullPath=True flag?

Comment: Yes, `fullPath=True` to return long names. `pm` is PyMel and uses wrappers to represent objects instead of strings. The major benefit is since the wrapper has a pointer to the actual object it's not name dependent. The main issue is that PyMel generally performs slower than `cmds`. And personally I found there was missing functionality in PyMel too. Have no idea what `mc` is, maybe you mean `OpenMaya`?

Comment: `cmds` works fine, but you do need to recognize the pitfalls. It recognizes objects as strings, which can be a problem. You can rename objects in different hierarchies with the same name so if duplicate names are in the scene then it's impossible for Maya to know what object you mean when using its short name, so use long names. Now the problem with long names is that it's based on its hierarchy. This means if you re-parent an object, it effectively changes its long name. Usually you can get around this by re-assigning the variable to the parent command as it returns its new name.

Comment: I read some python scripts that had .mc as short for "Maya Commands": but showed no real differences in functionality.

Comment: It's probably just `cmds` import as `mc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most issues were coming from ignoring long names. You can run a search on 'EDIT' to see where I left changes and comments:

```
'''
import DS_humanFingerPresetBuilder_V1
reload (DS_humanFingerPresetBuilder_V1)
DS_humanFingerPresetBuilder_V1.gui()
'''
import maya.cmds as pm

if pm.window("autoArmWin", exists =True):
    pm.deleteUI("autoArmWin", window = True)

myWindow = pm.window("autoArmWin",t='DS_handOmatic_V3',rtf=1,w=100, h=100, toolbox=True)
column = pm.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui(*args):
    pm.columnLayout()
    pm.button(w=300,label='Print Instructions(Check Script Editor)',c=printInstructions)
    pm.separator(w=300, h=3)
    pm.rowColumnLayout( numberOfRows=1 )
    pm.optionMenu('primePref',label='Select Primer',w=300)
    pm.menuItem( label='Build Offset Group')
    pm.menuItem( label='Prime Finger')
    pm.setParent('..')
    pm.button(w=300,label='Prime Game Finger',c=primeGameFinger)
    pm.separator( w=300, h=9)

    pm.rowColumnLayout( numberOfRows=1 )
    pm.optionMenu('axisPref',label='Select Aim Axis',w=300)
    pm.menuItem( label='X')
    pm.menuItem( label='Y')
    pm.menuItem( label='Z')
    pm.setParent('..')

    pm.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2)
    pm.optionMenu('sidePref',label='Select Side      ',w=300)
    pm.menuItem( label='lf' )
    pm.menuItem( label='rt' )
    pm.menuItem( label='ct' )
    pm.setParent('..')

    pm.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2)
    pm.optionMenu('fingPref',label='Select Finger  ',w=300)
    pm.menuItem( label='Index' )
    pm.menuItem( label='Middle' )
    pm.menuItem( label='Ring' )
    pm.menuItem( label='Pinky' )
    pm.menuItem( label='Thumb' )
    pm.setParent('..')

    pm.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2)
    pm.text(l='Set Increment  ')
    pm.textField('incText',it = '1',editable=True,w=220)
    pm.setParent('..')

    pm.colorIndexSliderGrp('controlColor',
        label='Control Color',
        min=0,
        max=31,
        value=1,
        columnWidth=[( 1, 80 ),( 2, 40 ), ( 3, 150 )])

    pm.separator()
    pm.button(w=300,label= "Build Finger Control",c=buildTemplate)
    pm.separator()
    pm.showWindow(myWindow)

    pm.separator( w=300, h=9)
    pm.button(w=300,label='Cleanup Heirarchy',bgc=(0.850,0.534,0.151),c=cleanup)

    # add increment to arm tool to allow multiple limb creation

def primeGameFinger(*args):
    primePref = pm.optionMenu('primePref',query=True,value=True)
    sidePref = pm.optionMenu('sidePref',query=True,value=True)
    incPref = pm.textField('incText', query=True, text=True)
    handSide = sidePref + incPref

    root = pm.ls(sl=True)[0]
    child = pm.listRelatives(root,f=True,ad=1,type='joint')  # EDIT: Use long names
    child.append(root)
    child.reverse()
    limbJnt = child

    print(child)

    if primePref == 'Build Offset Group':
        pm.group(n=handSide + '_hand_CTRL_offset_GRP',empty=True,world=True)
        pm.parentConstraint(handSide+'_wrist_BIND',handSide + '_hand_CTRL_offset_GRP',mo=False)

    elif primePref == 'Prime Finger':
        pm.parent(root,handSide+'_wrist_BIND')

        root = pm.ls(sl=True)[0]
        child = pm.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
        child.append(root)
        limbJnt = child

        #rename the arm joints
        for j, name in enumerate(child):
            pm.rename(name,'temp{0}_BIND_JNT'.format(len(child)-j))
            print(child)

def buildTemplate(*args):
    sidePref = pm.optionMenu('sidePref',query=True,value=True)
    fingerPref = pm.optionMenu('fingPref',query=True,value=True)
    incPref = pm.textField('incText', query=True, text=True)

    colorPref = pm.colorIndexSliderGrp('controlColor',query=True,value=True) #this variable links to the color slider group in the GUI
    colorPref = colorPref -1 # this reverses the first variable to ensure you are getting the proper color from the color selector

    fingerTemplate = sidePref +'_'+ fingerPref +'_'+ incPref

    lookFor = fingerTemplate +'AJ'

    #rename finger joints
    #list all joints in chain, this list will be refrenced by all the commands beneath it
    root = pm.ls(sl=True)
    child = pm.listRelatives(root,f=True,ad=1,children=True,type='joint')  # EDIT: Use long names
    child.append(root)
    limbJnt = child

    #rename the arm joints
    for j, name in enumerate(child):
        pm.rename(name,fingerTemplate + 'AJ{0}_BIND_JNT'.format(len(child)-j))

    #rename beggining and end joints to start and end respectivly
    root = pm.ls(sl=True)
    child = pm.listRelatives(root,ad=1,f=True,children=True,type='joint')
    pm.rename(child[0],fingerTemplate +'AJ_BIND_END_JNT')

    root = pm.ls(sl=True)
    rootJnt = root[0]  # EDIT: Need this for later.
    child = pm.listRelatives(root,f=True,ad=1,children=True,type='joint')  # EDIT: Use long names
    child.append(root)
    child.remove(child[0])
    child.remove(child[-1])
    limbJnt = child

    #build FK finger controls
    # EDIT: We're going to store objects we made in the loop here so we no longer need to hard-code names.
    orientGrps = []
    ctls = []

    for j in limbJnt:
            # EDIT: Since we are using these for names we need use split to convert from long names to short
            grpNName = j.split("|")[-1].replace('_JNT','Orient_GRP') #create the name for the first offset group 
            grpMName = j.split("|")[-1].replace('_JNT','Modify_GRP') #create the name for the second offset group
            ctlName = j.split("|")[-1].replace('_JNT','_CTRL') #create the name for the fk control (will eventually have shape and color options)

            #this block of text links back to the option menu and allows different shape creation 
            ctl = pm.curve(n=ctlName, d=1,p=[(0,0,0),(0,2,0),(-1,3,0),(1,3,0),(0,2,0)])  # EDIT: Assign the variable as you create it! No assumptions are made this way as Maya can split out a different output.

            grpN = pm.group(n=grpNName,em=1) # EDIT: Assign variable here
            grpM = pm.group(n=grpMName,em=1) # EDIT: Assign variable here

            # EDIT: Parenting changes the object's hierarchy, which also changes its long name. We need to reassign the variables as we parent to keep track of its new long name or we'll be referring to objects that no longer exist!
            grpM = pm.parent(grpM,grpN)[0] # EDIT: Important, need to parent this first because you're parenting ctl to this. If you do it 2nd, it will mess up ctl's long name.
            ctl = pm.parent(ctl,grpM)[0] #parent the control under the proper group 

            tmpCons = pm.parentConstraint(j, grpN,mo=False)#create temporary constraint to pop FK control offset into place
            pm.delete(tmpCons) #delete temporary constraint group when no longer needed

            linkCons = pm.parentConstraint(ctl,j,mo=False)#parent constraint the FK joint to the proper control

            pm.setAttr(ctl + '.overrideEnabled', 1)
            pm.setAttr(ctl + '.overrideColor', colorPref)#create a textfield for manually enterring the number of the color:

            # EDIT: Add objects to list.
            orientGrps.insert(0, grpN)
            ctls.insert(0, ctl)

            #this line is supposed to parent the finger fk controls properly: but it's being a little shit
            '''
            rel = pm.listRelatives(j, p=1)
            if rel:
                if lookFor in rel[0]:
                    rel = rel[0].replace('_JNT', '_CTRL')
                    pm.parent(grpN, rel)
            '''

    # EDIT: Beyond here was too hard-coded and would fail a 2nd time, so we must use our variables.

    #this chunk will be redundant when you figure out to make the list relatives above parent controls in the proper order
    pm.parent(orientGrps[2], ctls[1])
    pm.parent(orientGrps[1], ctls[0])
    #pm.parent(fingerTemplate+'AJ2_BINDOrient_GRP',sidePref+incPref+'_hand_CTRL_offset_GRP')

    #add attributes to controls
    pm.addAttr(ctls[0], ln='Y_Translate', attributeType='float', keyable=True)
    pm.addAttr(ctls[0], ln='Z_Translate', attributeType='float', keyable=True)
    pm.addAttr(ctls[0], ln='X_Translate', attributeType='float', keyable=True)

    #create and link nodes
    pm.setAttr(ctls[0] + '.Y_Translate',30)
    pm.setAttr(ctls[0] + '.Z_Translate',-30)
    pm.setAttr(ctls[0] + '.X_Translate',0.25)

    ctrlMultDiv = pm.createNode('multiplyDivide',n=fingerTemplate+'_meta_ctrlMultDiv')  # Assign variable to new object!

    #Build and connect Nodes for metacarpal rotation
    pm.connectAttr(ctls[0] + '.translateY', ctrlMultDiv + '.input1X')  # EDIT: Use variable!!

    pm.connectAttr(ctrlMultDiv + '.outputX', rootJnt + '.rotateZ')#joint Connect

    pm.connectAttr(ctls[0] + '.translateZ', ctrlMultDiv + '.input1Y')

    pm.connectAttr(ctrlMultDiv + '.outputY', rootJnt + '.rotateY')#joint Connect
    pm.connectAttr(ctls[0] + '.rotateX', ctrlMultDiv + '.input1Z')

    pm.connectAttr(ctrlMultDiv + '.outputZ', rootJnt + '.rotateX')#joint Connect

    pm.connectAttr(ctls[0] + '.Y_Translate', ctrlMultDiv + '.input2X')
    pm.connectAttr(ctls[0] + '.Z_Translate', ctrlMultDiv + '.input2Y')

    #figure out what X is supposed to do
    pm.connectAttr(ctls[0] + '.X_Translate', ctrlMultDiv + '.input2Z')


def cleanup(*args):
    pass

def printInstructions(*args):
    print"Step 1: Select your finger joint: it should have 5 joints"
    print"        -The first finger joint should be a matacarpal torwards the end of the wrist"
    print"        -until updated: it's recomended your finger joints have an X Aim axis"
    print"Step 2: If you are using the full autorigger, follow steps 3 through 4: otherwise skip them"
    print"Step 3: Hit prime game finger to create an offset group for your finger controls"
    print"Step 4: Change the pulldown next to Select Primer to PrimeFinger and hit Prime Game Finger again"

    print"Step 5: Select your aim axis"
    print"Step 6: Select your side"
    print"Step 7: Select your finger type"
    print"Step 8: with the root joint of your finger selected: hit build finger controls"

    print"Step 9: when you are finished, hit Cleanup Heirarchy to place it in the right place in the rig heirarchy(Full autorigger required)"

gui()
```

Now it's able to create a finger rig on multiple joint chains without running into naming conflicts.

Comment: Facinating, I never thought of turning maya nodes into variables. Thats going to make alot of lines shorter in my other scripts. Is there any good resources where I can get a better understanding on what j.split("|")[-1].replace is called and how to better implement it on other scripts?

Comment: Long names are separated with `"|"`, so you can split it with that character and use [-1] to get the last element, which is the object's name. Yes *always* assign a variable to commands that create objects, even if you supplied a name. If that name already exists Maya will auto-rename the new object, so you can't rely on a variable for its name.